# When will hit Sequence which selected in Fault Flow?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

I have created a custom fault sequence under /_system/governance/apimgt/customsequences/fault and selected the fault sequence in Fault drop down in API publisher. this fault sequence is never hit when backend returns other than 200 HTTP status code. when would the sequence invoked which selected in "Fault" drop down in API publisher ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fault sequence is only hit if anything goes wrong (i.e. exception or error) in the mediation flow. All responses from backend go to out sequence.

Please read https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Error+Handling for more information about the fault sequence.

If you want to handle responses from backend, you have to write a custom out sequence and do anything you want depending on the status code.